# Django forms & document.getElementById javascript - doesn't find id?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms

I have an app with a draggable marker on a map which populates the latitude and longitude. Beforehand, I was using a normal form where each input has an ID, this meant I could use document.getElementById('someformID').value to get the coordinates of the marker and input them into the form.

However, when using Django forms, each form element doesn't have an ID in the HTML, so instead I added it the forms.py file as an attribute. It now doesn't grab the coordinates however.

In the below code, I'm looking to get ***latcentre1*** and ***longcentre1*** from the Javascript

forms.py

```
class SafezoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Safezone
        name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'name'}))
        useremail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'useremail'}))
        latitudecentre = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'latcentre1'}))
        longitudecentre = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'longcentre1'}))
        fields = ['useremail', 'name', 'longitudecentre', 'latitudecentre']
        labels = {
            "name": "Name of safezone",
            "useremail": "Alert Email",
            "latitudecentre": "Latitude",
            "longitudecentre": "Longitude",
        }
```

From reference in HTML file

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript in the HTML file

```
marker.on('dragend', function() {
var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();

var latforform = lngLat.lat;
var lonforform = lngLat.lng;

document.getElementById('latcentre1').value = lngLat.lat;
document.getElementById('longcentre1').value = lngLat.lng;
```

Thanks!

Comment: open your browser, go to your form and right click -> inspect element. You will see all your html elements with the IDs. its probably `id_latcentre1`.,..

Comment: hero thanks! For others that come across this, like @hansTheFranz says, click inspect, look for the id of the input field, in this instance it was id_latitudecentre.